# How to get extension images file jquery.filer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, uploader

How to get extension file upload by jquery.filer and uploader 0.2

I want get extension php file uploader 0.2
you can see code on github
https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader

I'm tried to use this code

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["files"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
```

or

```
$name = $_FILES["files"]["name"];
$ext = end((explode(".", $name)));
```

but result : "" blank value

and tried again echo $_FILES["files"]
result is : "Array"

Please help to get extension file

Comment: please try do dump it like this: print_r( $_FILES["files"] )

Comment: Do `var_dump($_FILES['files']);` and post the result here.

Comment: same result not work

Answer (score 1):

```
$ext = substr(strrchr(strtolower($_FILES["files"]["name"][0]), "."),1)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.