# How to get file extension from class.uploader.php uploader0.2 jquery.filer

Tags: php, jquery, upload

How to get file extension from class.uploader.php not class.upload.php

class.uploader.php -> CreativeDream

Yesterday I have a question this link -> [How to get extension images file jquery.filer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934787/how-to-get-extension-images-file-jquery-filer)

https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader#options

after I read code class.uploader.php I wanna echo $metas['name']; but I don't know to print code please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
printe_r($metas['name'];
```

this is code you have to write.this code prints your variable

Comment: how to write database 
$exts = printe_r($metas['name']; not work

Comment: database?you want to write it in database?
you have to write print_r($metas['name']);;